# React Component Render in Container

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have a container that is passing props to a component and all works well when I console log however when I try and display this by mapping through the object it fails with a

> home4.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined(…)

What am I doing wrong please?

```
// Child component
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.scene);
    return (
    <div>

            {this.props.scene.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <div> {item.set}</div>
                    )
                  })}

      <button onClick={this.props.incClick}> Inc </button>
      <button onClick={this.props.decClick}> Dec </button>

    </div>
  );
  }
}


//container
let Container = createContainer((props) => {
  let doc = Scenes.findOne({sheet_no: props.myCount})
  return {
    scene: doc
  }
}, ChildComponent);
```

Comment: There is no native function map for objects. Scene is object in your app?

Comment: What does `console.log(this.props.scene)` print?

Comment: @p4sh4 it prints 
Object
_id : "8GcLgtgygJq3dd5gf"
project_ID : "1"
scene_no : "1"
set : "SCENE 1"
sheet_no : 1

Comment: Then @magnat is right, you can't map an object. `map` is an Array function, and there are no items to render. Your problem is outside of this code, in the parent component that is setting `this.props.scene` to invalid data.

Comment: findOne returns only one object as I assume. Am I right? Maybe you should render only {this.props.scene.set} ?

Comment: thanks both. I had tried rendering {this.props.scene.set} but get... home4.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined(…)

Comment: Ideally I just want to render each field in the child component

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that I am using this in Meteor

Comment: I have fixed it thanks. I needed to use find not findOne and then I could map through that array!